# Format jinja2 template if type is none?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am attempting to display some information back to a user. A phone number from a string in a database. Each client has 3 phone numbers, cell, home, other. At least one will be filled out but the others can be null.

When I formatting the numbers in jinja I am getting an error for None type. Is there anyway to skip the formatting if the value is None? here is the code..

```
{% for entry in results %}
<div class="panel-heading">{{ entry.firstName }} {{ entry.lastName }}</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <li>Email: {{ entry.email }}</li>
    <li>Cell Phone: {{ "%s-%s-%s" | format(entry.cellNum[0:3], entry.cellNum[3:6], entry.cellNum[6:10]) }}</li>
    <li>Home Phone: {{ entry.homeNum }}</li>
    <li>Other Phone: {{ entry.otherNum }}</li>
    <form action="#" method="post" class="sky-form">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ entry.id }}" name="firstname">
        <button type="submit" class="button">Select Client</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: "The phone numbers are stored as integers in the database." Are you sure you want to do this? Phone numbers can have leading zeroes.

Comment: Not related directly to your issue, but storing phone numbers as integers is a terrible idea. What happens if your phone number starts with a zero?

Comment: Well, at least that protects you against someone using a phone number such as ``#*76#*`` which could invoke funny functions on your local telephone system :)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I didn't think about leading zeros. Lucky the application is not too far along so changing shouldn't be a huge issue.. We'll see how much I break by setting the table to strings instead of ints..

Comment: I edited the above question and changed the values from int to string but am still running into an issue.. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the "cell phone" `li` in an `{% if entry.cellNum %}`?

Answer (score 3):

Jinja can display None types as "None". So that shouldn't be the issue.

The issue is most likely this part:

```
{{ "%s-%s-%s" | format(entry.cellNum[0:3], entry.cellNum[3:6], entry.cellNum[6:10]) }}
```

if `cellNum` is None or undefined etc. this will not work as it tries to reference the value. so call a if on `cellNum` first.

```
{% if entry.cellNum %}{{ "%s-%s-%s" | format(entry.cellNum[0:3], entry.cellNum[3:6], entry.cellNum[6:10]) }}{% endif %}
```

Also, I'm assuming that all your entries in `results` is a valid value/object to do this with, you may want to check that too.

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
{% if entry.homeNum %}{{ entry.homeNum }}{% endif %}
```

test data before using.